# Same mean, same SD, different spread

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance

In an experiment I'm running, I'm trying to determine if my light brightnesses are "clumped" or not. During the experiment, stuff will change rapidly from light to dark in a random way, but sometimes there are "clumps" remaining.

How do I differentiate between conditions where there are the same mean and standard deviation, but obviously look different. Imagine one where there's just random noise of mean=3 and SD=1, and another where it's completely black, but there is one high point, but still the mean=3 and SD=1.

Is that a 4rd moment test?  I don't actually know how the random noise is distributed. I've run some tests on it and get something that looks like a bell curve, matches a bell curve almost exactly visually. But is clearly very subtly not because the p-value for the Chi-squared is 0.0000001 (probably Gamma something something). Further, the random distribution is going to change throughout my experiment.  I really just need to be able to look for the clumps.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no finite number of moments (like expectation, standard deviation, skewness, kurtosis etc.) will uniquely determine a distribution. That is, two distributions can have the same first $n$ moments but still be "very different". That especially applies if your distributions are not from a specific parametric family, e.g., when some of your distributions are normal and others are multimodal.

In practice, you could of course try comparing higher order moments, and that might solve your specific problem.

Alternatively, you could either run statistical tests on whether two given samples come from the same distribution. Standard tests here are the two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov or the Anderson-Darling test. [What are the advantages (if any) of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test over other tests?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/610924/1352) does not yet have an answer, but may be a start.

Or you could calculate distances between two (or each pair of) samples, like the Wasserstein or Earth Mover's Distance, or possibly the Kullback-Leibler divergence, and see whether they are "far apart". Something like this would also allow clustering approaches based on the matrix of pairwise distances, if you have multiple samples and a clustering is of interest.